# How do I load an FPGA's Registers with Data?

Tags: verilog, quartus, intel-fpga

Note this question is not for when I am simulating. I have found numerous resources as to how to use `readmemh` which does not solve my problem. What I am trying to do is load the RAM for a processor that I designed with the program data. I believe that the FPGA is not getting any of the program data, just the HDL description of the processor.

I tried using Verilog's `readmemh` function, which I now realize is only useful for simulation. I have also tried using the `/* synthesis ram_init_file = "file.mif" */;` instruction (?). Either way, there was no difference in how the device worked. I simulated all these cases in ModelSim so I know the design works. I just am stumped as to how I can preload the data.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The answer is going to be tool specific because the `initial` blocks are, in general, not synthezisable. If you can do it, it is just because the tool has a specific template that is matched with your initial block. Initializing a memory is one of these special cases, where the 'initial' block is discarded from your logic but it is used to generate the initialization data passed along the bitstream.

From the [Intel Quartus documentation](https://www.intel.com/content/www/us/en/docs/programmable/683082/21-3/specifying-initial-memory-contents-at.html) we can see that there are slightly differences on the actual implementation of the two kinds of memories, dedicated RAM and MLABs, however the general idea is to use an `initial` block:

```
module ram_with_init(
   output reg [7:0] q,
   input [7:0] d,
   input [4:0] write_address, read_address,
   input we, clk
);
   reg [7:0] mem [0:31];
   integer i;

   // Init the memory with these values
   initial begin
      for (i = 0; i < 32; i = i + 1)
         mem[i] = i[7:0];
   end

   always @ (posedge clk) begin
      if (we)
         mem[write_address] <= d;
      q <= mem[read_address];
   end
endmodule
```

Or, for the quartus pro, you can use `readmemh, readmemb`:

```
reg [7:0] ram[0:15];
initial 
begin
    $readmemb("ram.txt", ram);
end
```

I suggest you look at the documentation linked as the most updated reference.